# Parsing Rails JSON in Titanium?

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-3, parsing, titanium, appcelerator

I am following the [Using JSON to Build a Twitter Client](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/appcelerator/appcelerator-using-json-to-build-a-twitter-client/comment-page-1/) tutorial, but I am trying to GET data from my own Rails API rather than Twitter. My JSON is being generated as follows:

```
[
  {
    "name":"Some Text",
    "created_at":"2011-05-15T15:33:37Z",
    "id":1,
    "image":
      {
        "url":"/uploads/image/1/2611c0.jpg",
        "thumb":
          {
            "url":"/uploads/image/1/thumb_2611c0.jpg"
          }
      },
    "updated_at":"2011-05-15T15:33:37Z"
  },
  {
    "name":"Some More Text",
    "created_at":"2011-05-15T15:43:37Z",
    "id":2,
    "image":
      {
        "url":"/uploads/image/2/2756c0.jpg",
        "thumb":
          {
            "url":"/uploads/image/2/thumb_2756c0.jpg"
          }
      },
    "updated_at":"2011-05-15T15:43:37Z"
  }
]
```

When I try to parse this array and then loop through it, I get this seemingly endless console message:

```
[WARN] [object TiUIView] has an auto height value of 0, meaning this view may not be visible.
```

As far as I can tell, this means that the array is empty, due to a parsing problem. To test, I created a simple label in my view and passed the original JSON object. It displayed correctly, so Rails is doing its job. Thanks for any suggestions!

**EDIT** Ti code as requested: http://pastie.org/1928676

Comment: Can you please share the Titanium code as well?

Comment: Did you try after giving a constant height to the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to take a guess and say that when you did you're test you didn't set the `row.height` to `'auto'`? By setting the `row.height` to `'auto'` and then it's child view that you add with a `height` of `'auto'` also you are assigning it a `height` of `0` like the warning above states. I would play around with giving the `row.height` something other then auto and see what you can do with that?

Comment: You did help me realize that I forgot about the parent `contentView`. This is where the problem is occurring since it is created before the `tableView` is created and populated with `rowData`. **If I set the `contentView` WITHOUT A HEIGHT and set the child views as `'auto'`, it works fine.** [The documentation says that 'auto' is the default](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.UI.View-object), so I don't understand why it matters.

Comment: Good call... a second look at your code and I realized I didn't go far enough down. Nice catch :-)